# How to adjust div location on animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In a webapplication I'm working on, when you click on a listitem, a div pops out. 
You can find an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yJYRZ/798/).

How can I adjust the top of the div to the listitem?

The div (`#home` in the example) has to pop out with the top next to the list item.

```
$(function () {

$("#home_link").click(function () {

    $("#home").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);

});
});
$(function () {
$("#edit_link").click(function () {
    $("#home").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
});
});
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. A fiddle is OK to include, but is not a substitution for including the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I cleaned up some of it and reorganized it. Basically, I marked a container element (which holds both the navs and the content), and use that to determine the desired offset. I made everything more generic so you can just add more hyperlinks as you need! Hopefully this is helpful, let me know if you have any questions about why I did things this way, or how something works.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJYRZ/801/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#list a").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $container = $this.closest('[data-id="container"]');
        var $target = $($this.attr('href'));

        $target.css('margin-top', $this.offset().top - $container.offset().top);
        $target.animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
    });
});
```